# How to retrieve strings from file after the blank string with cactoos?

Tags: java, oop, cactoos

I have a file, which is formatted like this:

```
header line 1
header line 2
header line 3

line 1
line 2
line 3
...
```

I need to get `Iterable<String>` with those lines (`line 1`, `line 2`, `line 3` etc.), after the header. How to achieve that with the help of [Cactoos](http://www.cactoos.org/)? The header is separated by the blank line.

I was able to skip the header lines with this code:

```
new Skipped<>(
    new SplitText(
        new TextOf(this.path),
        "\n"
    ),
    4
);
```

Now how to map the `Iterable<Text>` with the skipped header to the `Iterable<String>`?

I'm trying to do it with this code, which doesn't work:

```
new Mapped<>(
    new FuncOf<>(
        input -> input.asString()
    ),
    new Skipped<>(
        new SplitText(
            new UncheckedText(
                new TextOf(
                    this.path
                )
            ),
            "\n"
        ),
        4
    )
);
```

Comment: can you show what you did so far?

Comment: @sfat I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call:

```
new FuncOf<>(
    input -> input.asString()
)
```

You're actually calling `FuncOf<>(final Y result)`, which is not what you want.

Try providing a lambda as an implementation of `Func` instead. For example, the following works:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final String text =
        "header line 1\n" +
        "header line 2\n" +
        "header line 3\n" +
        "\n" +
        "line 1\n" +
        "line 2\n" +
        "line 3";
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(
        new Mapped<>(
            txt -> txt.asString(),
            new Skipped<>(
                new SplitText(
                    text,
                    "\n"
                ),
                4
            )
        ),
        Matchers.contains("line 1", "line 2", "line 3")
    );
}
```